# $A\in M(n;\mathbb{R})$ with $A^2=-E\Rightarrow n$ is even?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question from linear algebra which is the following:

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ square matrix whose elements are real. Suppose that $A^2=-E$, where $E$ is an $n\times n$ square identity matrix. Then $n$ in even.

I do not have any clue to this problem, but I think this problem can be shown by contradiction.

I appreciate any advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually, the identity matrix is denoted by $I$, not $E$.

Comment: @5xum: No. $E$ is also very common for the identity matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly, since $\det A^2 = (\det A)^2 = (-1)^n$, and squares cannot be negative in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Oh, it is so simple. I made my question complicated. Thank you very much!